# CLLocationManager's region monitoring vs significant location change

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, monitor, region

In the documentation, it's not clear how region monitoring is implemented. Is it purely based on significant location change, or is it a mixture of significant location change and standard location service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, I'd say it uses significant location changes until it's close enough to have to use more specific location updates, but I have no data to prove it. Only thing I'm sure of is that it works too accurate to be just significant location changes, and doesn't appear to drain battery, so I don't think it constantly uses more precise location updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it seems to be some sort of smart combination of two locating modes.

Comment: @lichen19853: I hope Filip is right (and therefore that I'm doing something wrong) but I'm only getting triggers every once in a while which leads me to believe that GPS is not taken into consideration.  FYI, I live in Eugene OR, a town of about 150,000...

Answer (score 0):

Ya region monitoring started after IOS 4.0 and latter devices, its also working when app is terminated or ideal mode means its not app dependent service it is a ios dependent service like local notification you find your location or give a certain location coordinate to the regin and set region monitoring after specific  given distance its enterin region and exitRegion methods called inside these function u do your wirk

Set a region

```
CLLocationDistance dist=200.0;
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:dist identifier:@"Test"];
    if([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled] && [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable])
        [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}
```